# Как прописать :hover внутри style=' '?

Tags: html, css

- Нет возможности подключить стили
- Нет возможности вставить стили между `<style> </style>`

`<div style="background: #333; padding: 10px;">Dark gray</div>`

Как прописать ему "ховер", к примеру `background: #555;` прямо внутри `style=""`?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Селекторы псевдоклассов не могут быть описаны прямо в теге. Раз нет возможности подключить стили, используйте события `onmouseover` и `onmouseout`.

```
<div style="background: #333; padding: 10px;"
   onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#555';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#333';">
      Dark gray
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Никак, **:hover** — это псевдокласс.

Comment: Это — комментарий ,не ответ.

Answer (score 0):

[А на w3.org написано что можно:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515)

> Setting properties on a source anchor for each of its dynamic states, using pseudo-classes:

```html
   <a href="http://www.w3.org/"
          style="{color: #900}
          :link {background: #ff0}
          :visited {background: #fff}
          :hover {outline: thin red solid}
          :active {background: #00f}">...</a>
```

Comment: приведенный сниппет - не работает. [Ответ на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles). Кроме того, ссылка в ответе ооочень старая (2002 год). [Вот новее](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/) и там ничего такого нет

Comment: буквы WD означают Working Draft, иными словами — черновик. В стандарте этого синтаксиса нет.

Comment: Ясно. Очень жаль.